# configure vpn so that it is not the preferred route

Tags: windows-xp, vpn

I recently re-installed XP on my PC. I had a vpn set up on the old system and remember being advised to change one setting so that it wasn't the preferred route for all network traffic. This was ideal as only connections to the target network would be made through the vpn and all normal traffic would go through the regular path unmolested. i remember thinking "why isn't this the default setting!?".

now i've formatted my drive and lost the config for that vpn (besides host, username, passwd).

does anyone know of the setting i'm referring to?

thanks, paul.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setting is under the properties of the VPN connection, TCP/IP settings > Advanced > untick 'Use default gateway on remote network"